# Searching in a JSON array with Perl

Tags: arrays, json, perl

I need to search for a specific term in a JSON array and get the index of the array element which contains the term as its value of a key, below is a sample JSON file that I'm working on, I need to get the array element whose "artifact_id" is "jar", so in this case I need to get the index of the array which is `1`, the "artifact_id" is guaranteed to be unique:

```
{
    "maven": [
      {
        "version": "1.2",
        "artifact_id": "zip"
      },
      {
        "version": "1.2",
        "artifact_id": "jar"
      }
    ]
}
```

I'm using the JSON lib and can decode the JSON to a Perl object, anyone can suggest the next step for me? Thanks a lot.

```
my $json_text = do {
               open( my $json_fh, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", $filename[0] )
               or die("Can't open \$filename\": $!\n");
               local $/;
               <$json_fh>;
};
my $json = JSON->new;
my $json_data = $json->decode($json_text);
```

Comment: if you're working on JSON and files, it might be worth looking at `JSON::Parse` which provides `json_file_to_perl`. Instead of your 8 lines of code, you could do:
`my $json_data = json_file_to_perl($filename);` ... but hey, doing it handcrafted is a good starting point and gain knowledge

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply iterate through your array, and store away the index once the matching node is found. The example below should speak for itself, but given the contents of your post I guess you should read up on loops, comparitive operators, as well as basic programming.

After you have decoded your JSON-data, there is nothing special about iterating over the array, after all; it is just an array (reference given the tree like structure of JSON).

```
use JSON qw(decode_json);

my $needle = "jar";
my $needle_location;

my $data = decode_json( join '', <DATA> );

while( my( $idx, $elem ) = each( @{$data->{'maven'}} ) )
{
    if( $elem->{'artifact_id'} eq $needle )
    {
        $needle_location = $idx;
        last;
    }
}

die "unable to find entry" unless defined $needle_location;
print "needle_location: $needle_location\n";

__DATA__
{
    "maven": [
      {
        "version": "1.2",
        "artifact_id": "zip"
      },
      {
        "version": "1.2",
        "artifact_id": "jar"
      }
    ]
}
```

```
needle_location: 1
```

Comment: thx! Just a side note, the `each` support for iterating through an array is not supported in Perl 5.10.x (and for some reason I cannot update to latest), so I need to replace it with a `for` loop something like ``` foreach my $idx (0 .. $#maven_array)```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on that of [Filip Roséen - refp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1090079/filip-ros%C3%A9en-refp), but hopefully a more advanced and abbreviated approach:

```
use Modern::Perl;

use List::Util qw(first);
use JSON qw(decode_json);

my $needle = "jar";
my $data = decode_json do { local $/; <DATA> };

my $needle_location = first( sub {
    my $artifact_id = $data->{ maven }->[ $_ ]->{ artifact_id };
    defined($artifact_id) && $artifact_id eq $needle
}, 0 .. $#{ $data->{ maven } } ) //
    die "unable to find entry";

say "needle_location: $needle_location";

__DATA__
{
    "maven": [
      {
        "version": "1.2",
        "artifact_id": "zip"
      },
      {
        "version": "1.2",
        "artifact_id": "jar"
      }
    ]
}
```